# Create a path of nodes from a list of strings using plain Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Cypher language only, based on a list of strings e.g [ "A", "B", "C" ], I want to create the following directed path:

`(n1:Test {ps: "A"}) -[:NEXT]-> (n2:Test {ps: "B"}) -[:NEXT}-> (n3:Test {ps:"C"})`

The input list can be of any length.
Some nodes and relationships can **already exist in the graph, hence reusing them**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it

```
WITH ["A","B","C"] AS nodeNames
WITH REDUCE(arr=[], i IN RANGE(0,size(nodeNames)-2) |
            arr
            +[[nodeNames[i],nodeNames[i+1]]]
) AS pairs
UNWIND pairs AS pair
WITH pair[0] AS from, pair[1] AS to
MERGE (n:Test {ps:from})
MERGE (m:Test {ps:to})
MERGE (n)-[:NEXT]->(m)
RETURN n,m
```